# How to clone egress UDP packets & send them to the same destination in order

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, openwrt

This is what I want,LAN---- (UDP packets flow)----->Router [Mirror UDP packets & send these packets to the same destination port/IP in order]--------> Internet.
Any idea?

Side note: I want to try if this work to reduce UDP packets loss by sending multiple packets to the destination server via it's IP or port.

Either method by port mirroring or Tee with syntax.

Comment: UDP is connectionless and unreliable. There are no guarantees that packets will arrive in order, nor even that they will arrive at all. Applications using UDP must accept the UDP limitations, or the applications must take steps to handle and mitigate packet loss and out-of-order delivery. In fact, sending duplicate packets to the destination can make things even worse because of increasing the network congestion, and the loss of packets due to network congestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't.

UDP is unreliable. The transport does not correct for lost or out of order.

Mirroring and sending to the same destination will make congestion worse. The application also would need to deal with duplicate data, which it may not. Even if it did work, in the best case mirroring halves goodput.

Instead, switch to a reliable in order protocol, either a transport or have the application do it. Many choices of transport protocol exist, QUIC is a popular UDP based one. TCP is also popular...